# How to make captions to center align on Images

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am using WP 5.3.2, with a customized (and old) Atahualpa theme. The new page I am struggling with, and am building with blocks, is http://www.allpowerlabs.com/chartainer where the caption under the thumbnail link left aligns despite the theme's apparent settings.

Older pagers built with the classic editor center the captions. I have seen various solutions in other threads, e.g. adding figcaption text-align css, but also that this is theme determined setting. My theme's editor shows these caption settings:

```
border: 0px solid #dddddd;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
padding-top: 4px;
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-khtml-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
```

I suspect this may be due to old HTML standards in the theme's PHP or CSS, but have not been able to figure out how nor where to insert changes (I am a designer not a coder and try not to touch the PHP, but only to use the theme's editor).

Answer (score 0):

You want to add this to your theme's css:

```
.wp-block-image .aligncenter > figcaption,
.wp-block-image .alignleft > figcaption,
.wp-block-image .alignright > figcaption,
.wp-block-image.is-resized > figcaption {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Make sure you get yourself familiar with the [browser developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css), you can check css there and change it temporarily to see the effects.